# Ada wrapper for CLIPS

Tags: ada, clips

I would like to use CLIPS inference engine from an ADA program.  Is there some example of an Ada package which implements (wrapper) a binding with CLIPS library (preferably its last version 6.3) ?

T.E.D wrote on this Forum in October 6 '09 that he realized this kind of wrapper but gave no more information.

---

Thank you Gary,

In your book "EXPERT SYSTEMS" you explain (p 384) that there is a version of CLIPS (certainly one of the first issues) developed entirely in Ada. 
In page 389 of the book the field type "external address" is explained to represent the address of a user-defined-function possibly written in Ada.
May be TED of AdaClips has still the source of his CLIPS wrapper. If he listens ...

Comment: I don't know of any wrappers that are available for Ada. The website for AdaCLIPS (www.telepath.com/~dennison/Ted/AdaClips/AdaClips.html)  is gone and I don't see any indications that the source is available elsewhere. You can see archived page at http://archive.is/J5aY1.

Comment: CLIPS/Ada used to be available from the Open Channel Foundation, http://www.openchannelfoundation.org/discipline/Artificial_Intelligence_and_Expert_Systems/, but apparently not any more. You can see the archived description here: https://archive.is/aLao4.

Answer (score 1):

The source for the CLIPS wrapper can be downloaded from http://web.archive.org/web/20151019121345/http://www.telepath.com/~dennison/Ted/AdaClips/AdaClips.html

Comment: Glad to see that nothing is definitly lost on the Web ! I will have a look to that. Thank you.

Comment: As the author, I believe I specifically licensed that software CC0 (essentially Public Domain) in hopes that someone would pick it up and make it a real thing. Perhaps someone will do so now?